# Javascript RegExp, fail in capture group

Tags: javascript, regex, capture-group

```
"aaa bbb ccc \n.000.\n 111".match(/^(?=\.).*(?=\.$)/m)
```

The result I am looking for in the above code is `000`
but keeps giving me `.000`, note the dot before the zeros.
Works OK for the last dot but not for the first.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you wanted to use a lookbehind (`/(?<=^\.).*(?=\.$)/m`), JavaScript doesn't have those. Use a capturing group instead.

```
/^\.(.*)\.$/m
```

E.g:

```
var match = str.match(/^\.(.*)\.$/m);
alert(match[1]);
```

Comment: Thanx... lack of lookbehind is the correct answer...   already solved the issue with the capture...  ?!Man... this was fast... someday someone is answering before we make the question... THX again!!

Comment: @ZEE, np, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer and up vote if it was helpful. ;)